# Magento production mode note set

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, nginx, php-7.2

Magento **production mode** note set display like http://prntscr.com/n6kl5q

> VPS server 8GB RAM, Nginx server  php vesion :Php 7.2
>   /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini   (php Memory limit =4G)
>   /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini   (php  Memory limit =4G)

How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be issue with compilation. Try compiling code(php bin/magento setup:di:compile) and check the errors generated. May be issue with your extension that is newly created or added.